# Firestore .orderBy Server Time Stamp not working SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a field "createdAt" which is a server timestamp it looks like this on firestore
[image]

When running my query without the .orderBy it works but when I add the order filter it stops working. 
I have tried switching the order of .orderBy and .whereField

```
let ref = Firestore.firestore().collection("posts")
     .order(by: "createdAt", descending: true)
     .whereField("author.uid", isEqualTo: uid)
```

and

```
let ref = Firestore.firestore().collection("posts")
    .whereField("author.uid", isEqualTo: uid)
    .order(by: "createdAt", descending: true)
```

Both do not work, but if I comment out the .orderBy line it works. 
Any ideas why this may be happening

Comment: Why is `.whereField("author.uid", isEqualTo: uid)` added twice to the query?

Comment: Typo I will update the question accordingly

Comment: .orderBy requires the field your ordering by to be included in the whereField. See [Order and Limit Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do something like this you will need to create a composite index.
When using an error handler in the query you will see that in the error message in the console is a message like this

> The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/project...

By clicking the link it will allow you to quickly create the index required to do that exact query. You can edit the default if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can get your response in array then make array as sort like below example:

```
self.arrCompletereq.sort(by: { ($0.actualdropOfDateTime ?? "")
.localizedStandardCompare($1.actualdropOfDateTime ?? "") == .orderedDescending})
```

Here `actualdropOfDateTime` is my one of key in database node

Comment: Are you suggesting to sort on the user side after getting all documents ?

Comment: @user6520705 Yes, this code working with me please try.

Comment: I am looking to use the .orderBy filter so that I can paginate my results

Comment: @user6520705 Please follow this Google firebase document hope it is work for you https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

Comment: Thanks, I have followed that at first but not sure why it is not working for me